# Can I replace P78E12-1000 with N7812-1C DC-DC converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am looking at a dual (+12V/-12V) power supply circuit, but I don't have a specific DC-DC converter in electronic shops that I have access to. Can I replace **P78E12-1000** with **N7812-1C**? I checked both datasheets and they appear to be very very similar - both 12V/1A out, same pinout, even Positive and Negative Output Paralleling Application Circuit and capacitor values are similar. But I'm still not 100% sure, maybe I need to look for some specific parameters.

[image]

[P78E12-1000 Datasheet (mouser.com)](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/670/p78e_1000-1480573.pdf)

[N7812-1C Datasheet (meanwell.com)](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=N78)